# How to find the file containing MetricsDataFile?

Tags: apex, api, managed-package, custom-object, query

We have installed the UsageMetrics App; however, we cannot access the file containing the data that contains the actual usage using the API (i.e., we see the reports on SF UI but we want to be able to query the data for each page/custom object). We are able to query the files as such

`'SELECT MetricsDataFile, NamespacePrefix, MetricsStartDate, MetricsType, MetricsDataFileLength FROM MetricsDataFile WHERE MetricsStartDate = LAST_N_DAYS:10 ORDER BY MetricsStartDate';`

How do I get the more granular data such as page visits for page A and store them on another custom object using the API? (I believe those are stored in a txt file).

Answer (score 0):

This information is on MetricsDataFile field. You need to un-encrypt the field in order to get a bunch of information in csv forma, I mean, it is a string where every valuable data is divided by ",".

My advice is to create a batch apex process that reads the information based on your query and then process MetricsDataFile field in order to move the data into a new custom object that you can use later on reports. This [blog](https://jsonhammerle.wordpress.com/2014/07/11/all-about-salesforce-usage-metrics/) is quite useful